# How to Update a datatable after file upload?

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, datatable, updates

I have a datatable, and a fileUpload. When I click the Upload button, I save it in my database but it is not updated in my datatable, so I need to refresh my page to show my data in datatable.
**My purpose is when I click the upload button, I save it in the database and update my datatable.**

My fileUpload :

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{cashMvtView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                                   multiple="true" update="form2" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|xls|xlsx)$/" />
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"  />
```

My datatable :

```
<h:form id="form2">
            <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="0">
                <p:tab title="Recherche" id="tabRech">
                    <p:dataTable var="cashMvt"  value="#{cashMvtView.listeFilteredCashMvt}" 
                                 selectionMode="single" filteredValue="#{cashMvtView.listeFilteredCashMvt}"
                                 selection="#{cashMvtView.selectedCashMvt}" 
                                 rowKey="#{cashMvt.id}"  tableStyle="width:auto"
                                 paginator="true" widgetVar="tabRecherche" id="tabRecherche"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"  rows="14"
                                 paginatorTemplate="{Exporters} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} 
                                 {RowsPerPageDropdown} {JumpToPageDropdown} {Controle}" 
                                 >
```

**Note : Although there is update='form2', it still not working.**

**Any other trick is accepted**

Comment: Have you inspected the XHR connection to view if there's any error?

Comment: Thank a lot @OscarPérez, you always help me, I fixed my problem by removing filtredValue from my datatable.

Comment: glad to have helped you. Please, if you can, add an answer explaining how did you found the solution. Then, if anyone else has the same problem will know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing filtredValue in my datatable.
I think that the real cause is in filtredValue, because when I upload my file, the data is saved in my database but it is not shown in my datatable due to the filtredValue.

Comment: Good for you that you found a solution! I was assuming that you actually had a need for the `filteredValue`.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for help me

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an `oncomplete="PF('myTableWidget').filter();"`
as follows:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{cashMvtView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                    oncomplete="PF('myTableWidget').filter();"
                    multiple="true" update="form2" sizeLimit="100000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|xls|xlsx)$/" />
      <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"  />
```

You also need to add a widgetVar to your table (`widgetVar="myTableWidget"`)

Comment: Better to try to get to the real cause if it not working instead of trying a workaround. And your workaround is not clear... What should `oncomplete="#{controller.update}"` do? And where is `public void refresh()` needed?

Comment: Edited, the function is: `update()` and it is called in the `oncomplete`

Comment: Not it is not! oncomplete is for calling client-side javascript functions and update is a java method. This method will be called render time and not when the oncomplete finished. So this won't work!

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This actually makes it easier: `oncomplete="PF('myTableWidget').filter();"`and no need for the method in the bean. I have not tried this, but this has worked for me with other elements.

Comment: Thank you guys,I fixed the problem by removing filtredValue in my datatable.

Comment: I think that the real cause is in filtredValue, because when I upload my file, the data is saved in my database but it is not shown in my datatable due to the filtredValue.

Comment: thinks for the answers, by the way can anyone have an idea how can i change the style of this component, it seems to me that primefaces does not give a much choices , any ideas ?

Comment: _"by the way can anyone have an idea how can i change the style of this component, it seems to me that primefaces does not give a much choices"_ Sure it does... It uses css...